# While trying to use the Passkit Java SDK I am see invalid key error: File does not contain valid private key: src/main/resources/credentials/key-java

Tags: java, sdk, key, passkit

I am using the java-passkit-quickstart to verify the PAsskit SDK for JAva, but everytime I try running the test, it gives me the error
File does not contain valid private key: src/main/resources/credentials/key-java.

I have generated the SDK credentials from developer portal and I have used the same password in the passkit.properties file, but I still se the same error.

Can someone help me with this issue.

I have generated the SDK credentials from developer portal and I have used the same password in the passkit.properties file, but I still se the same error.

I was expecting the code the to run without exceptions, but it did not help